# What would be the line by line analaysis and construction function T[n] with Big Oh notation?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, data-structures, time-complexity

[image: What is line-by-line analysis, Big Oh? and Construction time??]

What would be the line by line analaysis and construction function T[n] with Big Oh notation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you think? What is preventing you from solving this exercise?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!